# How to create a GPU VM with tensorflow or pytorch pre-installed?

Tags: google-dl-platform

I'm using Google Cloud. Is there a simple way to create a VM with GPUs, with TensorFlow or pytorch pre-installed?

Answer (score 1):

Use Cloud Launcher:

https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/deeplearning

You can launch the VM on Compute Engine, and options include a way to select what GPU hardware you want. You have to make sure that you have GPU quota in the zone, but other than that, it's quick and painless.

You can also launch the VM from the command-line using gcloud:

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="tf-latest-cu92" # or put any required
export ZONE="us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-instance"

gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
   --zone=$ZONE  \
  --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY  \
  --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release  \
  --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE  \
  --accelerator='type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1' \
   --metadata='install-nvidia-driver=True'
```

For pytorch, instead use:

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="pytorch-latest-cu91"
```

Official docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/), including a list of all available images.

Answer (score -1):

[Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) runs on GCE, has GPU support, and requires no setup.

GPU instructions on the site:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb

There are also a number of tutorials on GPU use in Colab, e.g.,

- [Useful snippets for Google Colaboratory. Free GPU included.](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/useful-snippets-for-google-colaboratory-free-gpu-included-d976d6b3e6de)
- [Google Colab Free GPU Tutorial](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d)

Kaggle Kernels also supports GPUs these days. [See here for more info](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/running-kaggle-kernels-with-a-gpu).